# How to get IRkernel to show leaflet result?

Tags: leaflet, jupyter-irkernel

I'm using leaflet in IRkernel, but the map produced doesn't show up in the output cell.

Actually, the map shows behind the cell, as can be seen from this figure, where the red arrow points:

[image: this figure, where the red arrow points]

Is there any way to fix it?

```
library(leaflet)
m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles()
m
```

I've notice the method to call saveWidget(), but the html file generated doesn't include Tiles layer.